# foursquare explore venue with query

Tags: foursquare

Trying to understand how the query parameter is suppose to be used when exploring venues in FourSqure.  A lit of POI providers have some kind of texted base search that is an additional filter for selecting places.

But this:
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?offset=0&limit=50&section=coffee&ll=38.0,-78.5&radius=40233.60&client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx&v=20121215

And this:
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?offset=0&limit=50&section=coffee&query=Starbucks&ll=38.0,-78.5&radius=40233.60&client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx&v=20121215

Returns the same information.  I would think having query=Starbucks would filter the list down.

Comment: You need developer credentials to access those results. Can you post the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query parameter does not work with the section parameter. If you would like to filter results to "Starbucks", omit the section=coffee parameter.